# Changing AVPlayerView background color

Tags: swift, macos, avplayer

Is it possible to change the background color of a AVPlayerView when used in a macOS application. I want to do this to remove the black bars when playing a video.

I've tried the following:

```
videoView.contentOverlayView?.wantsLayer = true
videoView.contentOverlayView?.layer?.backgroundColor  = NSColor.blue.cgColor
```

also tried adding these:

```
view.wantsLayer = true
videoView.wantsLayer = true
```

but the background is still black.

Answer (score 1):

AVPlayerView does not have layer after the initialization or setting wantsLayer property, but creates it later at some point. I was able to change the background with the next code in my AVPlayerView subclass:

```
override var layer: CALayer? {
    get { super.layer }
    set {
        newValue?.backgroundColor = CGColor.clear
        super.layer = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
videoView.contentOverlayView?.layer?.setNeedsDisplay()
```

try this maybe you just need to update the view. However if you would post more of your code I could try to help more.

Comment: This is not possible in a macOS application.